# Given facet information, how to efficiently check if a polyhedron composed of triangles is closed?

Tags: algorithm, polygon, graph-theory, computational-geometry

Let me clarify the definitions first. Consider a regular tetrahedron is composed of 4 vertices. Let's say the indices for these vertices are [0, 1, 2, 3]. Then, the definition of **facet information** is `F = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 3], [0, 3, 1], [1, 2, 3]]`. **A polyhedron composed of triangles is closed** if any triangle facet is connected to 3 other triangles via edges. For example, a regular tetrahedron is closed.

Then, given facet information, how to efficiently check if a polyhedron composed of triangles is closed?

A naive solution to do this is as follows: making a graph that describes unordered connections between facets, then check that any node is connected to 3 other nodes. However, this naive method seems too slow for my application.

P.S. my implementation for comparing number of edges and vertices in python

```py
    def isClosed(F): # F is list of indices triplet
        S = set()
        for triplet in F:
            for i, j in [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0]]:
                a, b = triplet[i], triplet[j]
                key = (a, b) if a < b else (b, a)
                S.add(key)
        return len(F)*3 == len(S)*2
```

Comment: *"A polyhedron composed of triangles is closed if any triangle facet is connected to 3 other triangles via edges"*. Is it valid to restate that as, "A polyhedron composed of triangles is closed if every edge that exists in at least one triangle, exists in exactly two triangles"?

Comment: I think it's equivalent.

Comment: In that case, a counting set should do the trick. The total number of edges is 3 times the number of triangles. The number of edges that are repeated must be half of the total. (So immediately, an odd number of triangles won't work.) For each triangle, add its edges to a counting set. When the repeat count for an edge reaches 2, increment the number of matches. If the repeat count for an edge reaches 3, fail immediately. After processing all triangles, the number of matches should be the total number of edges divided by 2.

Comment: Actually, I tried it ealier, but computation time to making a set of edges was computationally prohibitive to my applications...

Comment: That raises two questions. 1) How many vertices and triangles are you trying to process? 2) How did you implement the counting set?

Comment: Because I couldn't past the code here, I added above. the number of vertices are 15000 and facets are 29000.

Comment: Maybe, I just should try write it in c++... (but thanks)

Comment: There are improvements you can make to the Python code, but yes, C++ should be much faster.

Comment: @user3386109 I would be appreciate if you would point out possible improvement, but maybe just out of the topic

Comment: I don't think that `len(F)*3 == len(S)*2` is sufficient. That condition could be met even when there are unmatched edges, if some edges appear 3 or more times.

Comment: The improvement would be to eliminate the `i,j` loop. It would also help if the vertices in each triangle were sorted. Then you could just do `S.add((triplet[0], triplet[1]))`, and then two more lines like that for 0,2 and 1,2.

Comment: The answer depends on how the topology of the polyhedron is represented. You have to check if every edge belongs to two faces.